# How is variable named 'record' passed in function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a pivot table & was using a open source code and fumbled over this function.
How is record[] passed to this function? There seems to be no passing or any declartion. How can it come directly?

Whole code can be found here https://github.com/plotly/react-pivottable/blob/master/src/Utilities.js

I have tried looking up the whole module for record[] variable for could only find direct use. Could not find where it's assigned values.

```
sum(formatter = usFmt) {
    return function([attr]) {
      return function() {
        return {
          sum: 0,
          push(record) {
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat(record[attr]))) {
              this.sum += parseFloat(record[attr]+10000);
            }
          },
          value() {
            return this.sum;
          },
          format: formatter,
          numInputs: typeof attr !== 'undefined' ? 0 : 1,
        };
      };
    };
  },
```

I wanted to use & modify data provided at record[]
How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sample, `record` is a parameter of the function `push` on the object returned from the anonymous function returned from the anonymous function returned from (not a typo) the function `sum`.

Comment: In that case one last question, from where does [attr] has come up? 
I come from c++ background where you  pass parameters while calling functions. Here there seems to be no occurence of [attr] before. It just comes from nowhere.

Comment: `attr` is a (deconstructed) parameter, of the outer anonymous function returned from `sum`. The syntax may look unfamiliar. The function declared `function ([attr]) {...}` takes a single array parameter, and assigns the first element in the array to the parameter `attr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose this code as:

```
const func = sum(formatter = usFmt) // returns anonymus function([attr]) {}
const func2 = func([attr]) // returns function() {}
const myLiteral = func2() // returns object literal
```

And your literal is equal as below

```
myLiteral =  {
 sum: 0,
 push(record) {
   if (!isNaN(parseFloat(record[attr]))) {
     this.sum += parseFloat(record[attr]+10000);
   }
 },
 value() {
   return this.sum;
 },
 format: formatter,
 numInputs: typeof attr !== 'undefined' ? 0 : 1,
}
```

And on your `myLiteral` you can e.g.

```
myLiteral.push(myRecord);
```

Comment: Nice bifurcation. It look more clear now. One last question, how  are they using [attr] inside? They never passed it in sum( ) function.